# SwiftUI navigation bar inline mode searchable issue

Tags: swiftui

I've noticed a pretty big issue when using `inline` navigation bar display mode and `searchable` on my `List` in my app. When selecting the navigationlink it’s giving an undesired look when navigating to the view pushed. Using `automatic` display mode works just fine, and I don't see the issue.

I'm not sure why this is happening with display mode inline only. I'd rather not use `LargeTitle`'s, I just dislike the look of them. Is this a bug or a mistake I'm making. I wrote reproducible code below, any help would be appreciated.

**UPDATED APRIL 5, 2022**

It's been **two weeks** since I reported the issue to Apple. I've been unable to find any kind of solutions or temporary workarounds besides use Xcode 13.2.1 which isn't a fix in any kind of way. If anyone has any tips please do comment.

It seems Xcode 13.3 is the issue, I downloaded Xcode 13.2.1 and it's working just fine. I've reported this issue. You can see the same code working fine on previous versions. So anything above iOS 15.2 is broken and doing the same.

**Xcode 13.3 BUG**

[image: searchableissue]

**Xcode 13.2.1 Working**

[image: working-xcode-13.2.1]

```swift
enum Test: String, CaseIterable, Identifiable {
    case one
    case two
    case three
    case four
    var id: Self { self }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var search: String = ""
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List(search.isEmpty ? Test.allCases : Test.allCases.filter{$0.rawValue.localizedCaseInsensitiveContains(search)}, id: \.self) { item in
                NavigationLink(destination: Text(item.rawValue)) {
                    Text(item.rawValue)
                }
            }
            .searchable(text: $search, placement: .navigationBarDrawer(displayMode: .always), prompt: "Search")
            .navigationTitle("Searchable")
            .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a simple workaround, download Xcode 13.2.1. No bugs present when running it on iOS 15.4+. Compiling from an Xcode version before 13.3 seems to do the trick. I assumed I needed the latest version of Xcode for App Store submissions.